# I need a section title for a section that describes how a piece of software works

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, titles

Currently I'm using "How it works" as the title, but I want to replace that with something short and meaningful, most of my other section titles are one word long. The whole document is about a piece of software I developed. This section describes in detail how it actually works.

Comment: Perhaps "Functioning" might work, but that might imply a description of _what_ the software does rather than _how_ it does it.

Comment: I use "Internals" or "Internal Description"

Comment: @JohnLawler, Thanks for pointing that out, I've edited the question.

Comment: Ten letters. How much shorter do you want?

Comment: @DJClayworth, I'm looking for a word which is usually used in the same context, or a word that can convey the meaning without any ambiguity. Length in letters doesn't matter for me. If there is no single word , then something two or three words long would be fine I guess.

Comment: I guess my comment was code for myself stating that in my opinion simplicity in writing is a good thing, but that 'simplicity' should mean 'understandability' not low word count. I personally would use "How it works" because it's simpler than "functionality", for example. But that's just me.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I see what you mean but I asked this question hoping that there might be a better title. If there isn't then I'll stick with what I have.

Answer (score 1):

Why not *[functionality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/functionality)*

> The range of operations that can be run on a computer or other electronic system:
>   new software with additional functionality

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Comment: Interestingly this suggestion has more letters in it than the original.

Comment: @DJClayworth Then maybe *functions* for the same length?

Answer (score 1):

How about *[Mechanism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/mechanism)*

> A natural or established process by which something takes place or is brought about

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*

Answer (score 0):

*Mechanics* (normally used for video games, though) or *Usage*

Also if you want to be more general you could use *Tutorial*, but that might seem strange in a manual, since tutorials are usually hands-on (but not necessarily).

You could also go with *Operation*, depending on what the section contains.

Answer (score 0):

[*Design*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/design), [*Algorithm(ics)*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmics) as in the study of.

Answer (score 0):

It would likely depend on what you mean when you say your section describes "how it works."  That has various meanings in software engineering.

If you are describing the algorithmic methodology being used (e.g. "First the software totals all of the values for the first month, then calculates how the values for subsequent months change by dividing their values..."), then a title like *Algorithm* is most likely applicable, or for less-mathematical software, *Process*.

If you are describing not the algorithm but rather the particular implementation you have written (e.g. "The ImportManager object handles the higher-level process while farming out its domain-dependent behavior to one of three specific subclasses..."), you're likely looking for a title such as *Design* for a more detailed description or *Approach* for a more broadly-specified one.

If you are describing how a user is intended to interact with your software (e.g. "First, a user enters their name, then clicks through to the following screen where they can select from various avatars..."), you may be looking for a title like *Workflow*, or depending on the context and development process being employed, *User Story* or *Use Case*.